# PHP - Saving array to file - Not stacking up

Tags: php, arrays

Really stumped on this one and feel like an idiot! I have a small PHP cron job that does it's thing every few minutes. The client has requested that the app emails them with a daily overview of issues raised....

To do this, I decided to dump an array to a file for storage purposes. I decided against a SQL DB to keep this standalone and lightweight.

What I want to do is open said file, add to a set of numbers and save again.

I have tried this with SimpleXML and serialize/file_put_contents.

The issue I have is what is written to file does not correspond with the array being echo'd the line before. Say I'm adding 2 to the total, the physical file has added 4.

The following is ugly and just a snippet:

```
echo "count = ".count($result);"<br/>";
$arr = loadLog();
dumpArray($arr, "Pre Load");
$arr0['count'] = $arr['count']+(count($result));
echo "test ".$arr0['count'];
dumpArray($arr0, "Pre Save");
saveLog($arr0);
sleep(3);
$arr1 = loadLog();
dumpArray($arr1, "Post Save");

function saveLog($arr){
    $content = serialize($arr);
    var_dump($content);
    file_put_contents(STATUS_SOURCE, $content);
}

function loadLog(){
    $content = unserialize(file_get_contents(STATUS_SOURCE));
    return $content;
}

function dumpArray($array, $title = false){
    echo "<p><h1>".$title."</h1><pre>";
    var_dump($array);
    echo "</pre></p>";
}
```

Output View [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU8yZ.jpg)
Output File: `a:1:{s:5:"count";i:96;}`

I really appreciate any heads up - Have had someone else look who also scratched his head.

Comment: So, output view is right. You have added 7 to 82 and get 89. Where did you take `a:1:{s:5:"count";i:96;}`?

Comment: You are sure that no other instance of this script already re-writes to it after the script has written to it?

Comment: @u_mulder the "a:1:{s:5:"count";i:96;}" is the output of the destination file written by file_put_contents in saveLog function...

Comment: @CharlotteDunois At the moment this is in dev mode, if I open the output file and physically look, the "pre load" output as per the screenshot is correct, the "Post Save" output is correct, but if you immediately then go open the file, it has added twice.... there is no loop in the code, and nothing in log files to suggest it's been executed twice. Currently working on localhost and executing via my browser.

Comment: Once I had a weird issue where I always had the wrong location in my cache file but only on one page, on all the other pages the location was correctly written. I had to lock the file while writing to it by setting the flag `LOCK_EX`. I'm not sure if it will help you, but it's worth the try.

Comment: [Another screenshot here](https://img42.com/Kj72Q)

Comment: What happens before printing `end`? And if you run script via console?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - Thanks! had not used LOCK_EX - didn't help in this instance but good to know....

Comment: @u_mulder... nothing after end BUT running in console was fine... wtf? No idea why executing twice via the web. So confused! Thanks for heads up there, output is here:

root@server.d.co.nz [public_html]# php index.php
count = 7<p><h1>Pre Load</h1><pre>array(1) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(138)
}
</pre></p>test 145<p><h1>Pre Save</h1><pre>array(1) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(145)
}
</pre></p>string(24) "a:1:{s:5:"count";i:145;}"
<p><h1>Post Save</h1><pre>array(1) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(145)
}
</pre></p>root@server.d.co.nz [public_html]# tail status.log
a:1:{s:5:"count";i:145;}

Comment: Thanks so much everyone - will scrap browser based testing to complete this task!

Comment: So try to use some debugging - use `print_debug_backtrace` or `_SERVER` variable. Put them into log and see what requests and from what files are happening.

Comment: Thats another handy trick for debugging - thanks! Gave all the outputs I expected... just seems the script is executing twice when I refresh in my browser. Annoying but ok... moving ahead anyway - I do appreciate your help :)

Comment: Use `FILE_APPEND` constant to add content to a file with `file_put_contents` for debugging. Now everytime you do `fpc` you overwrite existing content, and you shouldn't.

Comment: Bingo.... FILE_APPEND helped... it was printing 2x "a:2:" arrays.... I then noticed a .htaccess file in the directory.... Chrome was looking for favicon.ico and .htaccess was sending it back to index.php to render a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Check .htaccess isn't sending 404 errors to the same script. Chrome was looking for favicon.ico which did not exist. This caused the script to execute a second time.